Dash Mantime Components not allowing icons
I am trying to use dash_iconify to use icons in my Plotly Dash App. I am trying to use something similar to this tutorial here: https://www.dash-mantine-components.com/components/navlink
However, in my application when I try to insert an icon inside of my dmc.Navlink, I am getting the following error: TypeError: The dash_mantine_components.NavLink component (version 0.14.0) received an unexpected keyword argument: icon
Allowed arguments: active, aria-, autoContrast, bg, bga, bgp, bgr, bgsz, bottom, c, children, childrenOffset, className, classNames, color, darkHidden, data-, description, disableRightSectionRotation, disabled, display, ff, flex, fs, fw, fz, h, hiddenFrom, href, id, inset, label, left, leftSection, lh, lightHidden, lts, m, mah, maw, mb, me, mih, miw, ml, mod, mr, ms, mt, mx, my, n_clicks, noWrap, opacity, opened, p, pb, pe, pl, pos, pr, ps, pt, px, py, refresh, right, rightSection, style, styles, ta, tabIndex, target, td, top, tt, unstyled, variant, visibleFrom, w
I have all libraries installed that should be and I have included the get_icon() function as well. This is the code I am using:
import dash_mantine_components as dmc
from dash import html
from dash_iconify import DashIconify


def get_icon(icon):
    return DashIconify(icon=icon, height=16)


html.Div(
    [
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="With icon",
            icon=get_icon(icon="bi:house-door-fill"),
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="With right section",
            icon=get_icon(icon="tabler:gauge"),
            rightSection=get_icon(icon="tabler-chevron-right"),
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="Disabled",
            icon=get_icon(icon="tabler:circle-off"),
            disabled=True,
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="With description",
            description="Additional information",
            icon=dmc.Badge(
                "3", size="xs", variant="filled", color="red", w=16, h=16, p=0
            ),
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="Active subtle",
            icon=get_icon(icon="tabler:activity"),
            rightSection=get_icon(icon="tabler-chevron-right"),
            variant="subtle",
            active=True,
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="Active light",
            icon=get_icon(icon="tabler:activity"),
            rightSection=get_icon(icon="tabler-chevron-right"),
            active=True,
        ),
        dmc.NavLink(
            label="Active filled",
            icon=get_icon(icon="tabler:activity"),
            rightSection=get_icon(icon="tabler-chevron-right"),
            variant="filled",
            active=True,
        ),
    ],
    style={"width": 240},
)

I've tried to roll back to other versions of dash_mantine_components but have not had any luck. This code is straight from the documentation.

Dash Mantime Components relies on Mantine react library, and since v0.14.0 DMC uses Mantine v7 which brings significant changes, among them :

icon prop was renamed to leftSection

That's it !
See also the documentation with examples that match a specific version of DMC.
